# Target estimate term in Firebase Push Notification

Tags: firebase, firebase-notifications

Recently i am working in a android project i want to use Firebase push notification.
I set up everything completely but when i send push notification i can see a term Target Estimate >1000 what's this means.

Answer (score 3):

This is:

> Estimated number of devices that this message will reach.